# php rename file with question mark invalid argument

Tags: php, file, rename

Good morning everyone,
my problem is that i can't rename a question mark file
This is the code

```
$file1 = $path . "disk/UFL/video-slave/2022-03-10/MPS-B_anonymous_17-26-40.mp4";
$file2 = $path . "disk/UFL/video-slave/2022-03-10/MPS-B_anonymous?_17-26-40.mp4";
    
rename($file1 , $file2);
```

The Warning message is:

```
Warning: rename(/var/www/html/disk/UFL/video-slave/2022-03-10/MPS-B_anonymous_17-26-40.mp4,/var/www/html/disk/UFL/video-slave/2022-03-10/MPS-B_anonymous?_17-26-40.mp4): Invalid argument in /var/www/html/monitor/rename.php on line 18
```

Thanks everyone in advance
Alberto

Comment: The Warning message is:

Comment: Does the filesystem that that file lives on permit `?` in filenames?